# Copy folders on release if included in VS-Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I created a **c# Project** in **visual studio 2015**. Now I have a folder in my project e.g.

```
foobar
```

When I call release, the folder is copied to `bin\release`. Now I have a second folder. e.g.

```
halloworld
```

Hitting the release will only copy `foobar`.

Atm I have 5 folders and two of them gets copied...

**How can I tell VS to copy that folder or not?**

Comment: Is there Content in your `halloworld` folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge it depends on the content of the folders.
If the folder contains nothing or just artefacts that get compiled VS thinks that there is no reason in copying them.

If you artefacts within your folders that should be copied to the output directory those folders will be copied.

Have a look at the properties of the folder content:

Here readme.txt will go to ABC/readme.txt
[image]

The class SomeClass will just get compiled...
[image]

If you want to create empty folders in your output directory, I would consider adding a custom task to your msbuild-project:

[See MSDN documentation for mkdir task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2448zz7.aspx)

**Edit by Dwza**: *(For all who may search the same)*

Total folders can be copied into `bin\release` or `bin\debug` by setting custom copy commands in

> Project > Properties > Build Events> Post Build

Sample

```
xcopy "$(ProjectDir)yourFolder" "$(TargetDir)newFoldername" /Y /R /I /E
```

For files you may use `copy` instead of `xcopy` since `xcopy` would check if its a folder or file...

```
copy "$(ProjectDir)folder\file.ext" "$(TargetDir)newFilename.ext"
```

If you more familiar with `xcopy` than you may have to use a hack to copy files

```
xcopy "$(ProjectDir)folder\file.ext" "$(TargetDir)newFilename.ext*"
```

The **`*`** in the end of the line will force `xcopy` to tread it as File.

Comment: That's the answer.

Comment: this is truely the answere... but should this say me, if i have a folder with e.g. 500 files... (css/js/html...) i have to set the permission to every single file ?

Comment: @Dwza You can do that for all files in one fo when you select them all in the solution explorer.

Comment: like i sayed that the answere, thats why its accapted. I still run into this problem because there is a tinymce folder that was in that project. it gets copied on build. I added a newer version but this folder is not copied. If I follow this informations, than I see, no file in that folder has an "copie" information...